# Output MySQL list of records, grouped by category?

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have data like this:

```
Category     Product
Mustards     Hot Mustard
Mustards     Horseradish Mustard
Mustards     Honey Mustard
Sauces       Tomato Sauce
Sauces       Barbeque Sauce
```

And I'd like to get this output:

```
Mustards
Hot Mustard
Horseradish Mustard
Honey Mustard

Sauces
Tomato Sauce
Barbeque Sauce
```

I thought I could do it with GROUP BY and/or DISTINCT, like this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT category, prodName
    FROM recipes
    GROUP BY category
    ORDER BY category, prodName ASC
```

but I'm not having much luck. Can anyone help?

Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(ProdName) as Product
FROM recipes
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category, ProdName ASC
```

**Output:**

```
CATEGORY     PRODUCT
----------------------------------------------------------
Mustards     Hot Mustard,Horseradish Mustard,Honey Mustard
Sauces       Tomato Sauce,Barbeque Sauce
```

#### [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1fad2/1)

Comment: Thanks - I'd forgotten about GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: My bad - I didn't know how to do that until recently.